# Should c++ constraints be evaluated eagerly or lazily?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, std-ranges

The main purpose of this question is to draw community's attention to libstdc++ ranges not working with clang: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46746

Avi Kivity suggested this is a gcc bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97120

But then he also suggested this is a clang bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47509

Rafael Ávila de Espíndola boiled down the problem to the following code, which compiles with gcc, but not with clang:

```
template <typename _Tp>
concept __member_begin = requires(_Tp __t) {
    {__t.begin()};
};
template <typename _Tp>
concept nothing = requires(_Tp __t) {
    {42};
};
template <typename _Tp>
requires __member_begin<_Tp> void __ranges_begin() {}
template <typename _Derived>
struct view_interface {
    void foo() requires __member_begin<_Derived> {}
    void bar() requires nothing<decltype(__ranges_begin<_Derived>())> {}
};
struct drop_view : public view_interface<drop_view> {};
```

clang complains (https://godbolt.org/z/4c45oKMKK):

```
<source>:14:42: error: no matching function for call to '__ranges_begin'
    void bar() requires nothing<decltype(__ranges_begin<_Derived>())> {}
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So the question is, who is right? Should this code compile or not?

And the more interesting question: can we please have working ranges with clang?

Comment: Asking "who is right?" requires referring to the standard, making this a language-lawyer question. Only having 5 tags means I had to pick other tags to remove, and the compiler tags seemed to be the best choice. Feel free to edit the tags if you want, but [c++] and [language-lawyer] should be in there.

Comment: Generally speaking, I am not sure if SO Question is the best way to "draw community's attention to libstdc++ ranges not working with clang".

Comment: @SergeyA: There's a surprisingly high number of people on SO who are deeply familiar with the C++ standard, including quite a few of its authors.

Comment: @MSalters I am not surprised by it, I am well aware of this fact. However, I am not sure that those people actively monitor question queue. I would believe, there are dedicated groups where such a message will be more visible.

Comment: I would hope that SFINAE would not apply to requires clauses.  It isn't needed (everything you can do with SFINAE you can do without in a requires clause), and it is conceptually complex.  Also, "have a member" requires shouldn't hard error just because someone called it, that makes auditing of requires clauses a pain.  So I hope clang is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the link from T.C.'s answer I found a related example in the standard, that clang refuses to compile. This is a clear indication of a bug in clang.

[[temp.constr.decl]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#4):

```
template <class T> concept C = true;
template <class T> struct A {
  template <class U> U f(U) requires C<typename T::type>;   // #1
  template <class U> U f(U) requires C<T>;                  // #2
};

template <> template <class U>
U A<int>::f(U u) requires C<int> { return u; }              // OK, specializes #2
```

[clang output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qETdxYxzT):

```
<source>:3:49: error: type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
  template <class U> U f(U) requires C<typename T::type>;   // #1
                                                ^
```

I created a dedicated bug for this: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50864

Answer (score 7):

[[temp.inst]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#17):

> The *type-constraints* and *requires-clause* of a template
> specialization or member function are not instantiated along with the
> specialization or function itself, even for a member function of a
> local class; substitution into the atomic constraints formed from them
> is instead performed as specified in [temp.constr.decl] and
> [temp.constr.atomic] when determining whether the constraints are
> satisfied or as specified in [temp.constr.decl] when comparing
> declarations.

Clang bug.