# Is the following case an issue with the new C++ concept standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, clang++, crtp, c++-concepts

Consider this program which uses the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename T>
concept Frobulates = requires (T t) { t.frobulate(); };

template <typename Derived>
struct S {
    int sidefumble() requires Frobulates<Derived> {
        Derived::frobulate();
    }
};

struct K: public S<K> {
    void frobulate() {}
};

int main() {
    K k;
    k.sidefumble();
}
```

When compiled, it generates this error using `clang++` version 13.0.0:

```
$ clang13 -std=c++20 ./recurring-concept.cpp -o recurring-concept && ./recurring-concept
./recurring-concept.cpp:17:7: error: invalid reference to function 'sidefumble': constraints not satisfied
    k.sidefumble();
      ^
./recurring-concept.cpp:6:31: note: because 'K' does not satisfy 'Frobulates'
    int sidefumble() requires Frobulates<Derived> {
                              ^
./recurring-concept.cpp:2:41: note: because 't.frobulate()' would be invalid: no member named 'frobulate' in 'K'
concept Frobulates = requires (T t) { t.frobulate(); };
                                        ^
1 error generated.
```

Specifically, the compiler reports that the type `K` does not have a member `frobulate()`, but this is plainly false.

I would expect that `sidefumble()` is compileable, just as it would be if the `requires` statement were not present.

- Is this expected/designed behavior? (It seems conceivable to me that possible use of the CRTP, being somewhat of an unusual corner case, might not have been accounted for in the design and/or implementation of this very young feature)
- At the very least, the error message is badly misleading. Where is the appropriate place to start a discussion among compiler/standards authors about the handling of this case?
- Is there a workaround?

Comment: @T.C., That seems likely to be related, but I'm not sure if it directly answers this case. It is helpful, though!

Comment: @trbabb TC is saying you are experiencing a clang bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug.

Though [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68118568/should-c-constraints-be-evaluated-eagerly-or-lazily) (thanks @T.C.) seems to outline slightly different scenario, the underlying bug seems to be the same.

[This comment in a clang bug thread](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44833#c10) contains almost exactly the same repro.